# How to avoid using temporary variable with std::modf?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, modulo, fractions, cmath

I've recently run into an issue where I got a segfault in MSVC where I wouldn't in GCC.

After hours I realized that apparently my version of MSVC does not support the following syntax:

```
double value = 3.4;
double fractional = std::modf(value, nullptr);
```

where I don't want/care about the whole part of the number.

Yes, I know I could do "3.4 - 3.0" or the like, but I'm concerned about specifically using modf in this way.  Currently I can only see doing this via:

```
double temp; 
double value = 3.4;
double fractional = std::modf(value, &temp);
```

Is there a way around this temporary variable?

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to use `modf`?

Comment: @Evg what else would you propose?

Comment: FWIW, `double fractional = value - std::floor(value);` is a lot cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: The standard doesn't mention a null pointer as possible argument so it's undefined.

Comment: @NathanOliver, this won't work for negative `value`.

Comment: @Evg Good point.  Pesky negative numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not need `value` afterwards you could call it as

```
double value = 3.4;
double fractional = std::modf(value, &value);
```

If you then still need the original value, you could reconstruct it easily.

**PS**: I did not find any mention of `nullptr` being a valid parameter. Maybe MSVC is right in going havoc.

**PS2:** I would not worry too much about the unecessary temporary. I would expect the compiler to generate similar code and explicitly mentioning the temporary is much cleaner and more readable as compared to passing `value` merely to avoid the temporary.

Comment: `std::modf(value, &value)` always makes me nervous.  I have to check to make sure the first parameter isn't taking by reference, otherwise there might be problems.  In this case it is fine, but it just triggers my paranoia.

Comment: I should have clarified, my issue isn't performance, it is the annoyance of having to use a temporary to get it to work which seems error prone, as in I might forget to do it.

Comment: @NathanOliver I wrote the answer and then looking at it I got super nervous, hence the "PS2" ;)

Comment: @opa I am not sure, but it might be that you are simply using the wrong function then. I would have to investigate a bit more, but I have the impression that `modf` is specifically for the case where you want both results. If you only want the fractional part there are other ways

Comment: I've checked C11 standard (where it came from originally) - no mention of second parameter allowed to be null.

Answer (score 5):

You could write a simple wrapper to do this:

```
double frac(double value)
{
    double temp;
    return std::modf(value, &temp);
}
```

This way the compiler can possibly optimize `temp` away.

EDIT: This can also be combined with @formerlyknownas_463035818's idea without losing `value`:

```
double frac(double value)
{
    return std::modf(value, &value);
}
```

Or even better, @NathanOliver's comment (EDIT thanks to @Evg's comments):

```
double frac(double value)
{
    int sign = value >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
    double avalue = std::abs(value)
    return std::isinf(value) ? 0.0 : sign * (avalue - std::floor(avalue));
}
```

<s>This one's best because it's clear and doesn't involve any tricks.</s>

Comment: Note that the second `frac` returns incorrect result for negative input: `frac(-3.14) = 0.86`, but it should be `-0.14`.